# Windows Store app, Is it any way to find Video Duration from Storage File? Other that getting duration from Media Element?

Tags: c#, video, microsoft-metro, duration

While checking with media element the duration is getting only after the media opened event.

Is there any other way to find Duration??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting duration of video file in Win Rt App or Metro C#

```
StorageFile videoFile; 
string path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path; 
videoFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(presentationItem.Slide_path_local);     
Windows.Storage.FileProperties.VideoProperties x = await videoFile.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync(); 
Duration videoDuration = x.Duration;
```